# EventHubClient.Send: A message cannot be sent because it is either received from a link or is already sent over a link

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-sdk-.net

There are two EventHubs in same EventHub namespace. I'm using EventHubClient.Send(EventData data) to send events, where both EventHubClient and EventData belong to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus namespace.

I wish to send the same EventData to both EventHubs belonging to same EventHub namespace. The second EventHub which receives data after the first EventHub, silently drops the data with the following exception:

'A message cannot be sent because it is either received from a link or is already sent over a link'

Can someone explain this behavior. I tried to find what this error means, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you cannot send the same `EventData` instance to multiple entities with the package that you're using.  You would need to create a new instance for each Event Hub.

The legacy package that you're using tracks the AMQP delivery state as part of `EventData`.  The error that you're seeing indicates that the internal state views this event as having already been sent and its delivery finalized.

If you'd prefer not to create a new `EventData` instance for this scenario, it may be worth considering updating to the current Azure SDK generation.  The `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` package does not have this limitation.

Comment: The first solution worked, I cloned the `EventData` and sent them to both EventHubs. Definitely wouldn't have figured out the root cause for this issue without your help. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that you're unblocked.